# Router with VLAN support

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I am looking for a router with VLAN support. But all routers I can find make no mention of their VLAN properties. Is it a standard for routers to have VLAN support? Is there any brand that has a good VLAN support?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question does not appear to be about computer software or computer hardware within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to consider the use of a custom firmware on a compatible router,
like `dd-wrt`, `tomato`, `OpenWRT` etc.

You will find more options for VLAN features that way.

Comment: Yes yes. And let’s not forget OpenWrt, which will let you do just about anything and is at least ten times more flexible. ;)

Comment: I knew I was forgetting a big one!. Thanks. Edited to add OpenWRT.